# Keep getting 403 response from Intuit AggCat API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I keep getting `403` from Intuit AggCat API in response to all requests except `getInstitutions` and `getInstitutionDetails` (they return correct data).  Has anyone else experienced that?

Ruby code excerpt:

```
IntuitIdsAggcat.config(:issuer_id => "...")
IntuitIdsAggcat.config(:oauth_consumer_key => "...")
IntuitIdsAggcat.config(:oauth_consumer_secret => "...")
IntuitIdsAggcat.config(:certificate_path => "...")
IntuitIdsAggcat::Client::Services.delete_customer '1'
IntuitIdsAggcat::Client::Services.discover_and_add_accounts_with_credentials 14007, 1,  { "onlineID" => "...", "passcode" => "..." }
IntuitIdsAggcat::Client::Services.get_customer_accounts 1
```

Response:

```
{:challenge_session_id=>nil, :challenge_node_id=>nil, :response_code=>"403", :response_xml=><UNDEFINED> ... </>}`
```

I am using https://github.com/rewardsummit/intuit_ids_aggcat

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for that response code is located [here]: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_%26_Categorization_Apps/AggCat_API/0700_Error_Codes

It looks like the users credentials either changed or they are locked.

regards,

Jarred